# vscode-icons extension: Cannot use custom icon

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, icons

So I saw that vscode-icons has no icon for assembly files (that end in .asm). So I wanted to make one. I looked at the documentation and stuff and got something. The icons for asm files (which are just a paper sheet normally) disappeared! I think it's because it can't find the image but I put the image at this file path : C:\Users<USER HERE>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\vsicons-custom-icons and still nothing.

Here is my settings.json:

```
{
    "vsicons.associations.files": [
        {
            "icon": "file_type_asm.png",
            "extensions": [
                "asm"
                ],
            "format": "png",
        }
    ],
}
```

Here is the tutorial I used:
https://medium.com/@chih.hsi.chen/how-to-add-your-custom-icons-to-vscode-icons-9ab8c3f9abc1

What is up with this?

Comment: i have same exact question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the extension's wiki in GitHub, and the source you provided,
the naming convention tells us to only use the full name in the name of the file on the local machine,
but when editing `setting.json`, in the icon part, just use the name you've given to the icon:

```json
{
    "vsicons.associations.files": [
        {
            "icon": "asm",
            "extensions": [
                "asm"
                ],
            "format": "png",
        }
    ],
}
```

*just pay attention that for folders, you have to make two icons, but add only one object to the array; one with `folder_type_` and one with `folder_type_***_opened`*

*one more thing to keep in mind for folders is that the array for folders is `vsicons.associations.folders`*

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It needed a full system reboot tho, so keep that in mind!